# Allow access to WordPress media file when user requirements have been met

Tags: arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I’m looking to hopefully write a function that protects WordPress media files (or more specifically pdf files).

I would like this function to run when a user attempts to access a specific file.

What I would like to happen is:

- User attempts to access url of specified file/files
- Function/Action runs the following checks

  - Check to see if user is logged in
  - Checks to see if user is either subscribed to a specific WooCommerce product, or has purchased a specific product.
  - If user meets the requirements, access is granted to files
  - If user does not meet the requirements they are directed to 404.

I realise WooCommerce already has a system for connecting files to products however having a function like this would be easier, as I plan to tie it in to ACF. I have a variation of this code working on the front-end however this does not protect the media files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) {
if (wc_memberships_is_user_active_member($user_id, 'gold-membership') || ( wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), 999 ) ) ) {

} } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better upload pdf to outside uploads folder of the Wordpress.
In the wp-content/uploads the files will stay public access.
Only read and offer files via script, this mode you can control the access of files.